# Shanling M0 DAP mounts in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: fuse

I insert a 1GB micro SD into this player and connect it to a Linux machine and it does not see the device. Connect it to a Win7 machine and it is immediately mounted.

It does charge from the Linux machine though.

Anyone had experience with M0 DAP and Linux yet?

I am in Fedora 27 with Mate desktop. It mounts everything and anything but not M0.

Comment: Is asking the manufacturer out of the equation?

Comment: What relevant output do you get from `dmesg`  as you connect the device? You've tagged with [tag:fuse]; are you using a FUSE filesystem, and if so which one?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my M2X on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. It was recognized very briefly but never mounted, dmesg indicated *device descriptor read/64, error -71 - USB problem* and intempestive power resets. I **deactivated the standbye functions** on the Shanling, and it worked after **a couple of computer resets and an SD card installation**. Now even the DAC works well, though it won't stay in 48 bits mode. **But I'm only able to access the SD card** that way.